# Does Processing plugin v2.10.1 not recognise SAGA?

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-processing

Version **2.9.3** of the *Processing* plugin works fine, I can run the SAGA tools successfully. Updating the *Processing* plugin to version **2.10.1** results in SAGA disappearing entirely from the toolbox. The path is fixed at:

```
C:\Users\Me\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga
```

Has anyone else come across this issue?

I'm using QGIS 2.8.2 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Same here; saga is not appearing in the advanced menu (even though it is activated in the *Processing | Options* menu. Also Grass and Grass 7 both show Missing depencies, even though both are installed and work when launched natively. Using Win 7 with QGIS 2.10.1 from the OSGeo installer. DJ

Comment: @paddleman - Thanks for confirming this buddy :). It's not a major issue for me but can be a bit of a hassle as I have to downgrade the plugin version whenever I want to use a SAGA tool.

Comment: It appears that they broke "Processing" just before the 2.10 release... there are some open tickets: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13072 and https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13188 etc

Comment: @markusN - Thank you for mentioning that this has been reported. I wonder where they went wrong =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded and installed **version 2.10.2** of the **Processing** plugin and it now recognises *SAGA*. As @markusN pointed out in his comment to my question, v2.10.1 had some issues but seems resolved now, atleast for *SAGA*.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when SAGA didn't appear in my processing toolbox (even though it was activated) the problem was the address that appeared for the SAGA folder in the: PROCESSING tab under OPTIONS then PROVIDERS then SAGA.

You need to find where the SAGA FOLDER has been saved on your PC and make sure that the address in this tab matches the folder address.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I already did that with the path I mentioned in my question (which I should have mentioned!) but still to no avail.